# How to wrap APIException message in array in one line in java

Tags: java, arrays, exception

I would like to write the thrown exception in one line of an array, other words, how can I wrap the first thrown exception into an array.

```
if (Books.size() == 1) {        
    throw new APIException("User.you.must.have.authority", new Object[] { requiredPrivs.get(0) });      
} else if (Books.size() > 1) {          
    throw new APIException(String.format("User.you.must.have.privileges", String.join(", ", requiredPrivs)));
}
```

so in this code, i want to make sure i format the thrown api exception in one arraylist line, any knda help is highly welcome

Comment: I can't figure out exactly what the problem is, could you please provide a little more detail?

Comment: Thanks jaybird, i would like to only wrap the exception into array format such that it looks a bit logical